# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:17.0.0-beta01

Tags: firebase, crashlytics-android

I was trying to implement the new Firebase-Crashlytics SDK. After going through the document, I got the following error.

Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:17.0.0-beta01.

Answer (score 20):

I found the following.

Wrong : com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:17.0.0-beta01.

Correct : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:**2.0.0**-beta01'

Comment: Nice catch! You might want to report this to the Firebase team with a request to update their documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great find saved me time :)

Comment: Thank's for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. The documentation that had the wrong version number will be corrected shortly.

Answer (score 7):

To implement the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK you need to add `firebase-crashlytics-gradle` classpath and `firebase-crashlytics` dependency.

In your project-level build.gradle file, add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have Google's Maven repository (if not, add it).
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        // ...

        // Check that you have the Google Services Gradle plugin v4.3.2 or later
        // (if not, add it).
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta02'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have Google's Maven repository (if not, add it).
        google()
    }
}
```

In your app-level build.gradle file, apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services Gradle plugin

// Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

In your app-level build.gradle, add dependencies for Google Analytics and Crashlytics.

```
dependencies {
    // Recommended: Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'

    // Add the Firebase SDK for Crashlytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta01'
}
```

From [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk?platform=android).

If you're migrating from Fabric, don't forget to update `google-services.json` (download it from your Firebase console). It could changed after migration. Migration is described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android).

P.S. answer for future strugglers.

Answer (score 3):

Updating these dependencies work for me

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.0'
    }
```